# Can UITextView be filled with text starting from bottom edge?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

How to make a `UITextView` to be filled with text starting from bottom edge, if it has unchangeable height?

UPD: The text in UITextView should be shown on the in the bottom despite the  UITextView's size.

Comment: can you make your question clear ? i think you are asking like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065693/how-to-set-content-inset-for-uitextview-in-ios7/19065802#19065802)

Comment: If you could attach a diagram or sample of what you want it would be easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your textView delegate:

```
    - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
        UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        inset.top = textView.bounds.size.height-textView.contentSize.height;
        textView.contentInset = inset;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Set self as the UITextViewDelegate.

```
-(void)resizeToContent
{
    if (self.alignBottomUp)
    {
        UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        CGFloat height = ceilf([self sizeThatFits:self.bounds.size].height);
        inset.top = self.bounds.size.height - height;
        self.textContainerInset = inset;
    }
}


-(void)setAlignBottomUp:(BOOL)value
{
    if (value != _alignBottomUp)
    {
        _alignBottomUp = value;
        [self resizeToContent];
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (self.alignBottomUp)
    {
        [self resizeToContent];
    }
}
```

See also: [UITextView doesn't update its contentSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143122/uitextview-doesnt-update-its-contentsize)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to align your text to the bottom of the `UITextView`.
As far as I know there is no built in way to do this so you'll have to write it by yourself.
Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235310/uitextview-alignment-to-bottom) which describes one possible way of doing this.