# UITextView doesn't update its contentSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, contentsize

I'm dynamically sizing a `UITextView`'s height and the height of the `UITableViewCell` it is embedded in when its content changes. But I also have the ability to paste in predefined bits of texts.

As this pasting happens programmatically, the problem is, that after adding the selected text bit to the `UITextView`'s text and calling my `UITableView` to update its cell heights, the `UITextView` hasn't yet updated its contentSize, which I use to calculate the cell's height.

Is there a way to force a **UITextView** to update its **contentSize**, after I programmatically add text to it?

Comment: For future viewers, I believe the real answer to this question is `textView.sizeToFit()`. I'm using this in Swift 2.0 and it works perfectly, just as @dkaisers requested, as long as you're using AutoLayout.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `sizeThatFits:` to get the correct size.

```
CGFloat height = ceilf([textView sizeThatFits:textView.frame.size].height);
```

Here is a popular open source component that makes use of it to achieve dynamic resizing based on the textview content:  
https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView

Answer (score 4):

Swift version of the answer:

```
var newTextViewHeight = ceil(textView.sizeThatFits(textView.frame.size).height)
textView.frame.size.height = newTextViewHeight
```

This piece of code might also come in handy if you want to update the superview of the `UITextView`

```
textView.superview?.frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height + 10
```